# How to determine if a cell is in the view port of a Virtual treeview?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

How to determine if a cell is in the view port of a Virtual treeview? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the control's `GetDisplayRect` method to find the coordinates of the node you're interested in. Specify the column, or -1 for the entire row. For invisible or filtered-out nodes, it will return `Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)`. Then check whether the returned rectangle is within the control's client area (`ClientRect`). You can use [`IntersectRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145001.aspx) for that part.